# How to get autocompletion for node module js/json config files

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, config, babeljs

I did a little research on this, but only found IDE specific answers for local projects, so I am gonna ask here.

**What it the best way to get general autocompletion for your module's config files?**

[image]

If you look at popular modules like `webpack` or `babel`, their config files (.babelrc, babel.config.js, babel.config.json, etc.) and maybe even their alternative entries in the package.json have somewhat solid autocompletion.

I found a `webpackConfig.json` schema file and `webpackConfig.d.ts` file inside `webpack`, but I am not sure how to full utilize these inside a private module project.

So, please be as detailed as possible for how to exactly do this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your editor, but generally auto-completion in the web ecosystem is done using TypeScript.

So if your editor supports TypeScript auto-completions (I know VSCode does), all you have to do is install the type definitions and tell the editor what's the type of the config file, and you'll get auto-completions and type-checking.

For `.json` files it's not as easy, if there is a json schema file you sometimes can add `"$schema": "path/or/url/to/schema/file"`.

For example for webpack you can use `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webpack/webpack/master/schemas/WebpackOptions.json"`.

Although, most tools support both `json` and `js`, so just use `js`.

Examples for common config files:

---

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('webpack').Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
    ...
};
```

`npm install --save-dev @types/webpack`

or

```js
/**
 * @type {import('webpack/declarations/WebpackOptions').WebpackOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
    ...
};
```

without any extra installs.

---

`.eslintrc.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config<import('eslint/rules/index').ESLintRules>}
 */
module.exports = {
    ...
};
```

`npm install --save-dev @types/eslint`

---

`babel.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@babel/core').TransformOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
    ...
};
```

`npm install --save-dev @types/babel__core`

---

`vue.config.js`:

```js
/**
 * @type {import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions}
 */
module.exports = {
    ...
};
```

No need to install anything, types come with the cli itself (`@vue/cli-service`).

---

If you need another file that I didn't cover, ask and I'll add it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think this is not 100% what I am looking for.
First, `webpack.config.js` does not require this kind of comment for it t work, the magic happens inside some webpack modules, I think.

So what we're trying to do is create a module that offers a config file like `myModule.config.js` to be placed in the consumers project that automatically gets autocompletion like webpack.

Comment: You have autocompletion for webpack only because you are using WebStorm... Again - to get autocompletion for anything else, add types